# Showing correctly a website on JEditorPane java

Tags: java, html, css, jeditorpane

I returned my JEditorPane in my program to a website, like google example,
but it doesn't show correctly the page, well without its css style.
 uh,
check my code :

```
JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane() {
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
            return true;
        }};

    editorPane.setEditable(false);

    HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
    Document doc = kit.createDefaultDocument();
    editorPane.setDocument(doc);
    editorPane.setEditorKit(kit);

    try {
        editorPane.setContentType("text/html");
        editorPane.setPage("http://www.google.fr/");
    }catch (IOException e) {
        editorPane.setContentType("text/html");
        editorPane.setText("<html>We can't load this page</html>"
                + e.getMessage() + " ");
    } 

    editorPane.setBounds(295, 265, 491, 474);
    editorPane.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));

    pan.add(editorPane);
```

I just want to show a website in a java component to show news and others information,
can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

A JEditorPane only supports basic HTML.

For full support you can use the default browser of your system. Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Integrate with the Desktop Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html) for a working example that uses the "BROWSE" functionality.